# Registering App on Single Device

Tags: android

I have created and developed an App and it has a **registration** page, Now let me rephrase in detail:

Registration will make an **entry** in **DB** through **API** call and suppose at sometime user **delete** the app since I dont have any uninstall listenner so the **data** is still **present** in DB and at registration there is a validation that ***no two users*** can have this same number since this user tries to register **again** then it will **prompt** him that user already exist like message which I am displaying because I dont want two device to get the same number.

Please tell me something to resolve this so that user acknowledges its device suppose I am sending mac-address along with it. Would it help?

Comment: how do you create the entry in the DB per user? What is is made up of?

Comment: @Redman Problem is I want to register again since "My app" no longer exist therefore I can register again with my number again and yes I have implemented OTP too

Comment: @Blundell Yeah I have created a table with user registering on app and otp is being generated

Comment: @Blundell For each User registering on app will create a row for this user

Comment: Doesn't it solve your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id/2853253#2853253 ?

Comment: Maybe I'll have to try but I guess this android ID is same as mac-address See my last line in a question I have written I posted this question maybe there is a more easier way

Comment: you could look at using Firebase for signin, i know they handle all this for you

Comment: @Blundell Firebase I guess that's paid ? I dont know please excuse my little knowledge but Can you tell me in brief?

Comment: @Divers your solution fails suppose same person want to register on another device by first deleting the app and going to register on the same device?

Comment: @SamH67 no it's free: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Comment: @Divers Sorry I mean register on different device

Comment: @Blundell So Do I have to use RealTime database?

Comment: @Blundell I have api which are feeding data into db so How will it work?

Comment: you can use the auth just for auth, then only use your other API's if the use is auth'd

Comment: @Blundell I am not getting which functionality do I have to use Authentication,Realtime database or storage?

Comment: Authentication.

Comment: @Blundell will see and inform you it works or not currently building all test cases and this test case is also included first I am assuring other things are perfectly placed and according to the requirement or not. Thanks Bud!